# Libnodave and Android Studio - Importing libraries

Tags: android, jar, libnodave

Is there a way to import Libnodave library in Android Studio? The only downloadable libraries that I could find were *.tar.gz extension. Does Android Studio accept only *.jar files for importing libraries?